# Python search exact word from list in string?

Tags: python, regex, list, search, find

I need to find exact word from list in the string.

I tried below code. Here I am getting exact match for single word from list but how to match two words from the list.

```
categories_to_retain = 
['SOLID',
 'GEOMETRIC',
 'FLORAL',
 'BOTANICAL',
 'STRIPES',
 'ABSTRACT',
 'ANIMAL',
 'GRAPHIC PRINT',
 'ORIENTAL',
 'DAMASK',
 'TEXT',
 'CHEVRON',
 'PLAID',
 'PAISLEY',
 'SPORTS']

x = " Beautiful Art By  Design Studio **graphic print** Creates A **TEXT** Design For This Art Driven Duvet. Printed In Remarkable Detail On A Woven Duvet, This Is An Instant Focal Point Of Any Bedroom. The Fabric Is Woven Of Easy Care Polyester And Backed With A Soft Poly/Cotton Blend Fabric. The Texture In The Fabric Gives Dimension And A Unique Look And Feel To The Duvet."

x = x.upper()

print x

#x = "GRAPHIC"
#x = "GRAPHIC PRINTS"


matches = [cat for cat in categories_to_retain if cat in x.split()]

matches

Output:
['TEXT']
```

Here you can see there is word present in my list called 'GRAPHIC PRINT'. I want find this word from my string.

Also i need to find word even if its present in plural or past tense. For example,STRIPED,STRIPE,GRAPHIC PRINTS etc.

Thanks ,
Niranjan

Comment: "graphic print" cannot be found because it is split into "**graphic" and "print**", I suppose.

Comment: Use a regex with boundaries

Comment: You need to create a split() function by yourself, that looks for words within those two stars as defined in your variable x.

Answer (score 3):

Use a regex with boundaries to get exact matches, even if you only had single words your logic would not work if you are trying to ignore any punctuation:

```
import re

patts = re.compile("|".join(r"\b{}\b".format(s) for s in categories_to_retain), re.I)

x = " Beautiful Art By  Design Studio **graphic print** Creates A **TEXT** Design For This Art Driven Duvet. Printed In Remarkable Detail On A Woven Duvet, This Is An Instant Focal Point Of Any Bedroom. The Fabric Is Woven Of Easy Care Polyester And Backed With A Soft Poly/Cotton Blend Fabric. The Texture In The Fabric Gives Dimension And A Unique Look And Feel To The Duvet."

print(patts.findall(x))
```

Which would give you:

```
['graphic print', 'TEXT']
```

Comment: thanks. its working for me. One more question what to do to match if word in list preset in plurals or past tense. For example if it contains graphic prints or texts or striped.

Comment: Add them to your list of words to match

Comment: For more complex processing of text you might want something like nltk, for a regex approach you can add optional characters using ?

Comment: ok thanks. I will try that one. I accepted your answer thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression, this will also help to avoid sequence of matching characters and exact input word will be displayed.

```
import re
matches = []
categories_to_retain = ['SOLID',
     'GEOMETRIC',
     'FLORAL',
     'BOTANICAL',
     'STRIPES',
     'ABSTRACT',
     'ANIMAL',
     'GRAPHIC PRINT',
     'ORIENTAL',
     'DAMASK',
     'TEXT',
     'CHEVRON',
     'PLAID',
     'PAISLEY',
     'SPORTS']

x = " Beautiful Art By  Design Studio **graphic print** Creates A **TEXT** Design For This Art Driven Duvet. Printed In Remarkable Detail On A Woven Duvet, This Is An Instant Focal Point Of Any Bedroom. The Fabric Is Woven Of Easy Care Polyester And Backed With A Soft Poly/Cotton Blend Fabric. The Texture In The Fabric Gives Dimension And A Unique Look And Feel To The Duvet."

x = x.upper()

print(x)

def searchWholeWord(w):
    return re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(w), flags=re.IGNORECASE).search

for cat in categories_to_retain:
    return_value = searchWholeWord(cat)(x)
    if return_value:
        matches.append(cat)

print(matches)
```

Output:

```
['GRAPHIC PRINT', 'TEXT']
```

Comment: Thanks Actually i did this at first place but the problem here is that it can also give me answer if its finds any word from my list in string for example  if it finds word like 'Texture' it will match 'Text'.

Comment: @Niranjanp sorry for the wrong reply, I have updated the code which uses regular expressions.

Answer (score -1):

Here you are splitting the string using default split(), which means it will be split at each space: there will be the strings "GRAPHIC" and "PRINT" in x.split(), but not "GRAPHIC  PRINT". You may want to use "if cat in x", which I believe would return what you need in this case.

This should work:

```
matches = [cat for cat in categories_to_retain if cat in x]
```

Comment: thanks. I did split to get exact match. If i do like this it will also match word like texture for the word text in my list.